# Azure Graph API - Approve PIM requests

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to **approve/deny** **requests for role activations** using the new Azure AD Privileged Identity Management REST API.

I am already able to read all pending role activation requests using the following request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignmentScheduleRequests
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#roleManagement/directory/roleAssignmentScheduleRequests",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "40b1dff9-9703-4da8-bf8f-275141347b6e",
            "status": "PendingApproval",
            "createdDateTime": "2021-06-04T10:47:40.34Z",
            "completedDateTime": "2021-06-04T10:47:40.15Z",
            "approvalId": "40b1dff9-9703-4da8-bf8f-275141347b6e",
            "customData": null,
            "action": "SelfActivate",
            "principalId": "049bad91-8812-4daa-870e-1edf05f5ced1",
            "roleDefinitionId": "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3",
            "directoryScopeId": "/",
            "appScopeId": null,
            "isValidationOnly": false,
            "targetScheduleId": "40b1dff9-9703-4da8-bf8f-275141347b6e",
            "justification": "My custom reason",
            "createdBy": {
                "application": null,
                "device": null,
                "user": {
                    "displayName": null,
                    "id": "049bad91-8812-4daa-870e-1edf05f5ced1"
                }
            },
            "scheduleInfo": {
                "startDateTime": null,
                "recurrence": null,
                "expiration": {
                    "type": "afterDuration",
                    "endDateTime": null,
                    "duration": "PT8H"
                }
            },
            "ticketInfo": {
                "ticketNumber": "",
                "ticketSystem": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Which matches the request I can see in the Azure Portal:
[image]

Now I am trying to *approve* the above request using the `PATCH` operation by providing the returned id:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignmentScheduleRequests/40b1dff9-9703-4da8-bf8f-275141347b6e
```

For the payload, I tried adding `Provisioned` and `Denied`:

```
{
    "status": "Denied"
}
```

But for whatever reason, I keep getting the following Error (Code 404):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://api.azrbac.mspim.azure.com/api/v3/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignmentScheduleRequests('40b1dff9-9703-4da8-bf8f-275141347b6e')?'.\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-06-04T11:06:18",
            "request-id": "ec668ea0-cf33-4e41-bfb4-19ca4ac683ad",
            "client-request-id": "ca765884-79b1-7695-5c72-c5783dd9968c"
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not able to find a "PATCH" request type in REST API documentation. Can you share a link to the documentation? Another thing I would recommend is to perform the same operation through Portal UI and observe the network tab to find out the exact request being sent by Azure Portal.

Comment: Hi Gaurav! Here is the link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/unifiedroleeligibilityschedulerequest-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
I already tried to observe the network traffic that the portal is using. Unfortunately, they are calling an internal API (api.accessreviews.identitygovernance.azure.com)

Comment: Looks like this beta endpoint is not working correctly although the beat document is ready. I have the same issue when I try to update any properties such as `justification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find a solution. Here is a complete sample using the PowerShell Graph SDK:

```
$scopes = @(
    "PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureAD",
    "RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory", 
    "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD"    
)

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes $scopes

[array]$pendingApprovals = Invoke-GraphRequest `
    -Method GET `
    -Uri '/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignmentScheduleRequests?$filter=(status eq ''PendingApproval'')' | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty value

$approvalSteps = Invoke-GraphRequest `
    -Method GET `
    -Uri ('/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignmentApprovals/{0}' -f $pendingApprovals[0].approvalId) | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty steps | Where-Object status -eq InProgress

$body = @{
    reviewResult  = 'Approve'
    justification = 'Seems legit'
}

Invoke-GraphRequest `
    -Method PATCH `
    -Uri ('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignmentApprovals/{0}/steps/{1}' -f $pendingApprovals[0].approvalId, $approvalSteps.id) `
    -Body $body
```

I also wrote a blog article about it:
[Approve requests for Azure AD roles in PIM](https://about-azure.com/approve-requests-for-azure-ad-roles-in-pim/)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using **roleAssignmentScheduleRequests** to get the pending request. Check out the response and in the value array there is an ID. Use that ID in the **Update privilegedapproval** call. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/privilegedapproval-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

```
PATCH /privilegedApproval/{id}
```

Example using the IDs you shared:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedApproval/40b1dff9-9703-4da8-bf8f-275141347b6e
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 180

{
  "approvalState": "approved",
  "approverReason": "Martin Brandl approves you!"
}
```

In the request body for approval state your possible values are: pending, approved, denied, aborted, canceled.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the endpoint you are referring to (/priviledgeApproval) is deprecated and in fact when I call it, I get the following error : `The current endpoints of AAD roles have been disabled for the tenant for migration purpose`. The solution I am looking for should use the unifiedRoleManagement API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-apis