# I am not able to approve my Azure active directory (PIM) pending request programmatically through Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am try to approve the prividedge identity management (PIM) request through graph api but when i try to approve it the api is return forbidden. See the below screenshots

[image]

The pending request should be approved.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to know what API permission you consented for using this graph API, because to be honest, I didn't find this graph API, I only found [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/azure-ad-pim-approval-workflow#approve-the-activation-request-step) which contained the API request you used.

According to the error message, I'm afraid you gave the `wrong api permission` or you `used client credential flow` to generate the access token to call the API. So it's better to provide the request you used to generate access token.

Finally, I found an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455530) which successfully call the API but with Powershell script. According to this sample, we should give `PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureAD,RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory,PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD` **delegated API permission** and use it to generate access token. We need to use `auth code flow/ROPC flow` so that the token generated should contain `scp` claim with API permissions as value. Then using that token to call the API.

You may try request below to generate the access token for a test:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=azure_ad_app_id_consented_api_permission
&scope=PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureAD RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD
&username=user_name_better_to_use_account_with_Global_Administrator_role
&password=password
&grant_type=password
```

Comment: Yes I used the same doc you mention.

Use Client Credentials to9 generate the token.

Api permission are 

AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All
PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureAD
Application
PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureADGroup
Application
PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureResources
PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD
PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup

Comment: ok then I think at least you can take a try with adding the api permissions and generate the access token. I don't have a test result in my side so I can't test it for you.

Comment: PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources

RoleAssignmentSchedule.Read.Directory
Delegated

RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory
Delegated

RoleManagement.Read.All

RoleManagement.Read.Directory

RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory

User.Read

Comment: you'd better not to use the client credential flow, and the 3 api permissions, pls consent `delegated` api permission

Comment: Can we connect on google meet? Need your guidence.

Comment: "message": "User : 5e4642c4-3c2f-4b5e-bc32-aaea0ecd904c is not an authorized approver for approval : aa99ec88-28f0-4143-896b-5c278147c42d",


I have the global administrater role. what else?

Comment: no I can't, I just want to double confirm that, can you approve that user's request in Azure portal? Just like what [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/azure-ad-pim-approval-workflow#view-pending-requests) showed. If you can do it in portal, could you pls try the API again? The error message looks like the approver doesn't have enough permission.

Comment: Thank you I generated the token and nmow it is working thanks alot sir